# Replicat Abended with ORA-02290: check constraint (TABLE_NAME.CHK_JSON) violated

Tags: oracle, database-replication, transactional-replication, oracle-golden-gate

We see the below in my Discard file -

NOTE: I can see the record in my source db.

CI Error ORA-02002: error while writing to audit trail
ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCHEMA_NAME.CHK_JSON) violated (status = 2002), SQL <INSERT /*+ RESTRICT_ALL_REF_CONS */ INTO "SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE_NAME" ("INSTRUMENTID","INDEXDETAIL","CREATIONTIME","LASTUPDATEDTIME") VALUES (:a0,EMPTY_CLOB(),:a2,:a3) RETURNING "INDEXDETAIL" INTO :dl0>
Aborting transaction on /local/dbms/oracle/goldengate_dbfs/oggma/goldengate_trails/oggma_deployment/var/lib/data/tc beginning at seqno 22 rba 206,136,818
error at seqno 22 rba 206136818
Problem replicating CATALOG_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME to SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME.
Mapping problem with insert record (target format) SCN:12.1.6904...
*
INSTRUMENTID = 11111111
000000: 42 32 37 41 42 37 42 31                         |11111111        |

INDEXDETAIL = (LOB)
CREATIONTIME = 2022-05-30 06:20:15
000000: 32 30 32 32 2d 30 35 2d 33 30 20 30 36 3a 32 30 |2022-05-30 06:20|
000010: 3a 31 35                                        |:15             |

LASTUPDATEDTIME = NULL
*

Process Abending : 2022-06-01 07:32:44.534819

Answer (score 0):

May I know what type of Replicat you are using? Whether Audit is enabled? Also, could you please share the full GG version.

You can also refer to this KM note which might help you.

ORA-2002 And ORA-22275 Encountered When SELECT Audit Is Turned On For A Table (Doc ID 2764792.1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).